# What is the purpose of /usr/prog directory

Tags: linux, centos

While reading some internal documentation, I unexpectedly stopped at the following word sequence: "as most other software available at `/usr/prog` ...". I've never heard of the directory, but the context is CentOS and I am rather new to CentOS as well.

Rapid web searching shows that the directory is indeed used by different software (in particular, I saw that python installation sometimes lives there), but I can not see where the directory is documented anyhow for CentOS or other systems. Is there a resource where one can read about it?

Comment: In the entire history of CentOS I've never seen that directory used anywhere. It is certainly not created by the system or any system package. I also have no idea what you found on a web search, as I couldn't find anything at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just googled `"/usr/prog"` and see from the snippets that the directory is mostly used instead of `/usr/local`. I thought that there was some tradition behind that.

Comment: Well, I finally found a few results for ancient non-Linux systems, and a few modern ones regarding specialized scientific software (academic stuff always seems to do a lot of strange things that make no sense to anyone in IT, but they just don't care). Have you got something specific?

Comment: @MichaelHampton hmm, strange scientific habits make sense as an answer in my case. I will try to find some of those who might have influenced the decisions here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Local to your site, you can put things wherever you want, including /usr/prog.

No one has bothered to document this as any kind of convention. Linux FHS, as well as hier man pages from a variety of systems, say nothing about it. Who knows where it came from originally.

On a system following FHS, site local software would be in /opt.  Maybe /usr/local.